# Flutter web custom url route results in 404

Tags: flutter-web, firebase-hosting, flutter-getx

I'm using flutter web to build a website. I have two main routes in my website, a LoginPage which also is the initialRoute and a HomePage.
I'm using [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) to move between routes and I set up the path navigation strategy using the [url_strategy](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy) package.

**Main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'website',
      unknownRoute: GetPage(
        name: '/notfound',
        page: () => UnknownRoutePage(),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/LoginPage',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/LoginPage',
          page: () => LoginPage(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/HomePage',
          page: () => HomePage(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Meanwhile everything works fine when I'm debugging on my pc (even with flutter run --release) I get problems when I deploy the website on Firebase Hosting.

Let's say I try to reload a page (like for example [www.website.com/LoginPage](http://www.website.com/LoginPage)) I get the default page not found from Firebase Hosting (even if I set a custom notfound page) while I sould expect to be redirected to the LoginPage of my website.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I figured out how to resolve this issue, just added

```
"rewrites": [ {
   "source": "**",
   "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

to my firebase.json file.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!